# Given a recursive function, show there is a n such that Wn is recursive

Tags: recursion, computability

> Let $f$ be a recursive function. Show that there is an $n$ such that: $W_{n}$ is recursive; and $(\mu y)[ W_{y} = \overline{W_{n}} ] > f(n)$. *Hint:* Enumerate a finite set $W_{n}$ by first computing $f(n)$ and then defining $W_{n} = K \upharpoonright (f(n) + 1)$, where $A \upharpoonright x$ denotes the restriction of $A$ to elements $y<x$.

For the first one, I have an intuition that there are also infinitely many ones, because if there is one, by the padding lemma we can obtain the rest. The problem is that I can not find a formal argument for the existence.
For the second one, I do not understand why do we need such enumeration.

Comment: I think you haven't copied the problem text correctly: "$(\mu y)[W_y=\overline{W_n}]$" doesn't mention $f$, and isn't a "complete sentence" in terms of mathematical grammar (it's basically just a "noun").

Comment: Yes, there was an error, the comparison term was missing.

Comment: If, by "infinitely many ones",  you mean infinitely many $n$'s, then remember that, when  you pad to  get a bigger $n$, you also get a different (possibly much bigger) $f(n)$.  If, you mean infinitely many $y$'s, then remember that you care only about the smallest $y$.

Comment: Yes, I mean infinitely many $n$'s, but probably I am not reading the exercise in the correct way. I see the first question independent of the second one (not vice versa), but it makes me think what does $f$ have to do there.